# Find text within multiple elements jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First, this is probably a duplicate. Just couldn't find any answers that worked for me.

I have a block of elements like this

```
<a id="folder" href="http://example.com/update.php?dir=%2Fexample%2Fimg">
    <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
    img
</a>
```

is there any way for jquery (or just js) to find the text inside there? I'd like it to return 'img' when given that setup.

Thanks in advance, Michael

Comment: Go into Developer Tools. Click on the element. At the bottom of the elements window it will display the full selector for the element.

Comment: @Barmar did you even read the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply `$("#folder").text()`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I dont know how i didnt see this in the first place lol

Answer (score 0):

Let us know what else you want to do with this.

```js
var all = $('a').text();
alert(all);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="folder1" href="http://example.com/update.php?dir=%2Fexample%2Fimg">
    <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
    img
</a>
<a id="folder2" href="http://example.com/update.php?dir=%2Fexample%2Fimg">
    <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
    van
</a>
<a id="folder3" href="http://example.com/update.php?dir=%2Fexample%2Fimg">
    <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
    project
</a>
<a id="folder4" href="http://example.com/update.php?dir=%2Fexample%2Fimg">
    <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
    fun
</a>
<a id="folder5" href="http://example.com/update.php?dir=%2Fexample%2Fimg">
    <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
    picnic
</a>
<a id="folder6" href="http://example.com/update.php?dir=%2Fexample%2Fimg">
    <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
    car
</a>
<a id="folder7" href="http://example.com/update.php?dir=%2Fexample%2Fimg">
    <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
    wagon
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string search() method.

var str = "This is test";
str.search("is")

will return you, first match of the regular expression inside the string, in this case 2.

Checkout

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search

Comment: You can combine with $(element).text();